# C++ Pointer to template class type, required use of parentheses - why?

Tags: c++, parsing, templates, pointers

I have a class which uses a template type, and I needed to declare a pointer to an instance of that class.

Here is an example of such a class:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class PlaneSection
{
    // Code here
}
```

I tried to declare a (const) pointer, like so:

```
PlaneSection<4>* const plane_section_ptr = &plane_section;
```

Where `plane_section` is an instance of the class `PlaneSection`.

However, this would not compile. (The error g++-4.8 gave me was `error: missing template arguments before '*' token`.

So then I tried this:

```
((PlaneSection<4>)* const) plane_section_ptr = &plane_section;
```

Which then compiled.

My question is why do I require an extra 2 pairs of parentheses? Why is `((PlaneSection<4>)* const)` valid, but neither `(PlaneSection<4>)* const` or `PlaneSection<4>* const` are?

**EDIT**

I recompiled again, but this time I had to change it to:

```
(((PlaneSection<4>)*) const)
```

Comment: I'm very suspicious of [every part of your post](http://ideone.com/d9r3Cz).

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting, different compilers parse this differently? I think IDE One compiles correctly, and g++ may not do?

Comment: ideone uses g++. You need to add more information to your post.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is it possible this could be a g++ bug? 4.8 isn't an official release yet, as far as I know. I'll try updating it. (Haven't `sudo apt-get` for a while now)

Comment: Unless you're using the vintage Turbo C++ from 1983, I'd be very surprised if any half-decent compiler failed on your code.

Comment: @EdwardBird: I've been using a released GCC 4.8.1 for months...

Comment: @zneak I'm compiling with codelite ide, g++ 4.8. I'll try a terminal compile

Comment: 4.8 came out late spring/early summer IIRC. I can also confirm that it compiles absolutely fine with 4.2.1, which I still have because of Xcode.

Comment: You should try to compile the snippet Kerrek posted to ideone. I bet it'll work. If it doesn't, your g++ is borked. If it does, you need to isolate a little more in which circumstances this happens.

Comment: @zneak I've tried it again, changed my compiler to version 4.7 and version 4.8... Same result `missing template arguments before '*' token`

Comment: @KerrekSB I've tried your test example, which I have now got working. (Compiled from command line, not codelite)

Comment: @KerrekSB I've now setup another test project... This compiled fine, just 1 warning about unused variable.

Comment: Curious, what happens if you remove the const requirement?  Is the code in your post exact?  I.E. you didn't define any CTORs or any non-dependent calls like might be the case discussed here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fname_binding.htm  Although your code may not have this issue maybe the compiler is somehow confused about something related to this...

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you may have some hidden unicode character in your source. Try deleting that line and rewriting it.

Comment: @GManNickG I tried building from the command line and it worked, so I deleted my ide's project config files and then tried what you suggested. I think it was one of these things which fixed it... I was having some problems with the makefile (which is auto generated) complaining that I had deleted a .cpp file from the project, which I had done from within the ide, but it got "confused". Anyhow, I think your suggestion fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Eric Sorry I didn't get chance to try that.